# Formula to calculate the number of possible models with hierarchical structure

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**Please Note:**
On the surface this question may appear like a statistics question, however I believe that it is a question related to combinatorics and therefore it is more suited in the math stack exchange.

**Statement of Problem**

I would like to calculate the number of possible candidate models, given a set of covariates $x_1, \ldots, x_p$. The models have a hierarchical structure.

Initially the linear terms are considered. If a linear term is added to a model and considered significant, then its quadratic term and all two-way interaction terms are also considered (both quadratic and two-way interactions are considered together).

For example, consider a model with 2 covariates $x_1$ and $x_2$. The set of candidate models for the linear terms are:

Model 1: $y = \beta_0$

Model 2: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1$

Model 3: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_2x_2$

Model 4: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2$

If Model 2 or 3 is successful, then we have the following candidate models with quadratic terms:

Model 5: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_{(1q)}x_1^2$

Model 6: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_{(2q)}x_2^2$

If Model 4 is successful, then we have the following candidate models with quadratic and/or interaction terms:

Model 7: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_{(1q)}x_1^2$

Model 8: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_{(2q)}x_2^2$

Model 9: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_{(1q)}x_1^2 + \beta_{(2q)}x_2^2$

Model 10: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_{12}x_1x_2$

Model 11: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_{(1q)}x_1^2 + \beta_{12}x_1x_2$

Model 12: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_{(2q)}x_2^2 + \beta_{12}x_1x_2$

Model 13: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_{(1q)}x_1^2 + \beta_{(2q)}x_2^2 + \beta_{12}x_1x_2$

When there are 2 possible covariates, we have 13 possible models. The list of candidate models gets larger as the number of covariates increases.

Is there a formula to calculate the number of candidate models for $p$ covariates that have this hierarchical structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if you have $n$ covariates you start by checking $2^n$ models,

and there are ${n \choose k}$ of these that use $k$ of the covariates with $0 \le k \le n$.

If one of those is successful then you need to check a further $2^{k(k+1)/2}-1$ models, so $2^{k(k+1)/2}$ including the original successful one.

So the answer may be $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} 2^{k(k+1)/2}$$ which seems to be related to [OEIS A006898](https://oeis.org/A006898), which is in turn related to [OEIS A006896](https://oeis.org/A006896) described as *"the number of hierarchical linear models on n labeled factors allowing 2-way interactions (but no higher order interactions)"*